# button with shadow that look like gradient in android xml

Tags: android, xml, selector, shadow

i am trying to achieve this button with selector that on press the shadow is removed..

[image]

but i can seem to get close to this..this shadow is from all side and look like is it not reaching to the corners , can i get this effect via xml ?

this is my xml which is close to the image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" >
        <layer-list>
            <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" >
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="6dp" />
                    <gradient android:angle="45" android:endColor="@color/white" android:startColor="#D6D6D6" />

                </shape>
            </item>
            <item  android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
                <shape
                    android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>

                    <corners android:radius="6dp" />

                    <padding
                        android:bottom="10dp"
                        android:left="10dp"
                        android:right="10dp"
                        android:top="10dp" />
                    <stroke android:width="0.5px" android:color="@color/gray_50"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>


<item>

    <layer-list>
        <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" >
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="6dp" />
                 <gradient android:angle="45" android:endColor="@color/white" android:startColor="#D6D6D6" />

            </shape>
        </item>
        <item  android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/white"/>

                <corners android:radius="6dp" />

                <padding
                    android:bottom="10dp"
                    android:left="10dp"
                    android:right="10dp"
                    android:top="10dp" />
                <stroke android:width="0.5px" android:color="@color/gray_50"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>


</item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this as background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
       <solid android:color="#fff" />

       <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
       <corners android:radius="4dp" />

       <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#dadad7" />

       <solid android:color="#fff" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

I hope it will work

Comment: This ain't gradient :( it's solid like a rock

Comment: Where is the gradient? This question has been incorrectly marked as good.

Comment: @DanA.S. increase number of <item> attributes by decreasing opacity will add gradient